# Auto Complete a Select with sub array Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, angularjs

I have a json array, and the key contains one sub-array. I want to create two *selection*. In the first one, the user can show the list of data; the second one is empty. When the user select some item, the second *selection* auto complete with the sub array.

For **example**, look this: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udivop/8/edit?html,js,output)

What I mean is to create 2 section. The first one has:

```
 - main001
 - main002
 - main003
 - main004
```

the second selection is empty. I, for example, I click 'main002', I want that angular fill the second selection with  2sub1

```
 - 2sub1
 - 2sub2
```

How can I do it?

***Thank you!***

**Update**: EXAMPLE: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2HYgpzEauHliIQ46nTr1?p=preview)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: easy way out is cascading selects

Comment: I've tried this: http://plnkr.co/edit/2HYgpzEauHliIQ46nTr1?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution **FOUND**: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8teDJOuFWTbK02QTmg3p?p=preview)

```
    <select ng-model="select.id_1" ng-options="a.id as a.value for a in resources.animals" ng-change="firstChange(select.id_1)">
  <option value="">-- choose animal --</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="select.id_2" ng-options="a.id as a.value for a in Subarray" ng-if="Subarray">
  <option value="">-- choose name --</option>
</select>
```